# RavenDB - why there is no DeleteAsync method in IAsyncDocumentSession

Tags: c#, ravendb

Why there is no `DeleteAsync()` method in `IAsyncDocumentSession` - part of RavenDB's client for C#. I would expect all operations to have an async equivalent, not just `StoreAsync` and `LoadAsync`.

```
public interface IAsyncDocumentSession : IDisposable
{
    void Delete<T>(T entity);
    void Delete(string id);
    (...)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that `Delete` is not asynchronous operation. It marks the document/entity to be deleted when you call the `SaveChangesAsync` method.

On the other hand, `LoadAsync` and `StoreAsync` are asynchronous operation. `LoadAsync` would load the document asynchronously and `StoreAsync` can generate the document's ID asynchronously by making a request to the next `HiLo` range.